# Adding Meta Data to socketio-file-upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have the `socketio-file-upload` plugin to upload photos on my server with NodeJS, this work, but when I try to use the plugin functionnalaty to add some data to the upload, the script get stuck.

**Client side**

```
var uploader = new SocketIOFileUpload(socket);
uploader.listenOnInput(document.getElementById("upload"));

uploader.addEventListener("start", function(event){
    event.file.meta.hello = "world";
});
```

**Sever side**

```
var fileUpload = require("socketio-file-upload");
fileUpload.listen(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var upl = new fileUpload();
    upl.dir = "img";
    upl.listen(socket);

    upl.on("start", function(event){
        console.log(event);
    });
});
```

The error comes from the client side where the event argument has no meta object, and when you decide to create one the server side doesn't receive it

[The documentation of socketio-file-upload on Adding Meta Data](https://github.com/vote539/socketio-file-upload#client-to-server-meta-data)